# What does "fade" mean in this case?

Tags: meaning

Do we use "fade" to ask someone to move slightly to their right side? The sentence is: "Fade 20 degrees to your right".

The context: The a woman's monitoring the screen to guide a man. And she said to the man: "Fade 20 degrees to your right."

Please kindly help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source?

Comment: Hi Katy, it's not online so perhaps the full conversation would help you understand. I'll see you both soon. Okay, I'm reading you both.
Keep straight ahead. Fade 20 degrees to your right. Hey, you're a little loose. Tighten up.

Comment: Is this in the context of flying an aircraft or something?

Comment: Yeah, she's on the aircraft and guide the man outside through monitor.

Comment: This is technical jargon then. It'd take someone knowledgeable in that field to say what it means.

Comment: No, we don't. As others have pointed out, this is technical jargon. As a general rule of thumb, don't generalize from oddball lingo you've only seen once.

Answer (score -1):

This meaning of "fade" is used in a military, aeronautical, or nautical context.  If the woman and man in your example are members of the military, or a spy organization, or a criminal organization, or if the speaker intends to imitate the speech patterns of one of the above, than the usage would be appropriate.

"Fade" is generally never used in this way when in non-militaristic contexts.

Comment: So what does it mean?

Comment: This sounds more like a comment than an answer